# why the difference in cuda cores between nvidia control panel and device query?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

Q1: why there is different information i got from Nvidia control panel->system information and information from device query example in cuda sdk.

system information:

- cuda cores 384 cores
- memory data rate 1800MHz

[image: Nvidia Control Panel]

device query output:

- cuda cores= 2 MP x 192 SP/MP = 576 cuda cores
- memory clock rate  900MHz

[image: Device Query output]

Q2: how can i calculate the GFLOPs of my GPU using device query data?
the most common used formula i found was the one mentioned [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522964/calculatin-flops-of-gpu/?offset=2) which suggest using Number of mul-add units, number of mul units which i don't know?

Max GFLOPS (Cores x SIMDs x ([mul-add]x2+[mul]*1)*clock speed)

Comment: The answer to Q1 is right in the second screenshot you posted. The deviceQuery utility you are using is too old and has assumed the incorrect number of cores per SMM (192 instead of 128).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: It tells you right there just above the line...

> MapSMtoCores for SM 5.0 is unefined. Default to use 192 Cores/SM

Maxwell, the architecture behind the GeForce 840M, uses 128 "cores" per "SMM"

```
3 * 128 = 384
```

Q2: `"Cores" * frequency * 2` (because each core can do a multiply+add)